# R Reporters to Officer and migration

Tags: r, officer, reporters

I have a lon script written with the Reporters package and I want to migrate it to officer, will I be able to know if there are sources which indicate the functions of each package?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [officeverse docs](https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/index.html) are really good. They don't have one-to-one ReporteRs translations but when I had to migrate I was able to quickly do so by just referencing those docs.